# Implement portal using createPortal and ReactDOM - converting from Nextjs code to React.js code

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am converting the next.js code to react.js .I am using portal for the first time can anyone please help to where should I place the `<div id="photo-picker"></div>`
The above code was place in document in next.js. My question is that where should I place in my react.js project...please help me to complete my project.

I am expecting that it should be in app. but do not know how

Comment: function App() {
  return (
    <StateProvider initialState={initialSatate} reducer={reducer}>
      <Router>
      <div>
        <section>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Login />}/>
            <Route path="/onboarding" element={<Onboarding/>}/>
          </Routes>
        </section>
      </div>
    </Router>
    </StateProvider>
    
      
  );
}

Comment: my app js look like where to place the above code....

Answer (score 0):

Portals are generally used to dynamically change the position of an element in the DOM. Portals are great to use when showing a modal, drawer, galleries etc. I'm guessing that your element has the similar use, so you can try putting your portal container element  (`<div id="photo-picker"></div>`) inside `/public/index.html` after the `<div id="root"></div>`. This way elements need to be rendered on top of your application (`<div id="root"></div>`) will be displayed properly.

Comment: ok i have question that i am using firebase signInWithPopUp now when click the login botton it work well but double clicking gives an error Firebase: Error (auth/cancelled-pop-up-request)

Comment: can you please help me with one also

Comment: @161_SumanMaji I don't know much about firebase unfortunately, I can't help you with this one. You should also post it as separate, another question. There will be users who can help you with it. By the way, it my answer solved your question consider giving an upvote and marking it as "correct answer". Thanks and good luck with your project!